# Python NumPy array of objects where each object is a different size NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to create a numpy array of objects, where objects are the other numpy arrays have different or exact dimensions. The purpose is to have advanced indexing while working with an array of arrays where nested arrays might have different sizes.

If all the nested arrays have different dimensions then all is OK:

```
a = np.array([np.array([0, 1], dtype=int), np.array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int)], dtype=object)
print(a[0].dtype, a[1].dtype)
```

In that case, dtype of all the nested arrays is equal to 'int64'.

But when the nested arrays have the same dimensions then nested arrays becomes also the arrays of objects:

```
a = np.array([np.array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int), np.array([3, 4, 5], dtype=int)], dtype=object)
print(a[0].dtype, a[1].dtype)
```

In that case, dtype of all the nested arrays is equal to 'object'.

The same situation for single array in the list converted to array of objects:

```
a = np.array([np.array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int)], dtype=object)
print(a[0].dtype)
```

The question is: What is the proper way to create the array of objects where each object is the NumPy array with different dimensions to have nested arrays of dtype=int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first case with mixed subarray sizes:

```
In [477]: a = np.array([np.array([0, 1], dtype=int), np.array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int)], dtype=
     ...: object)
     ...: 
In [478]: a
Out[478]: array([array([0, 1]), array([0, 1, 2])], dtype=object)
```

With same sizes, `numpy` makes the highest dimensional array it can - 2d:

```
In [479]: a = np.array([np.array([0, 1], dtype=int), np.array([1, 2], dtype=int)], dtype=obj
     ...: ect)
     ...: 
In [480]: a
Out[480]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 2]], dtype=object)
```

The fact that the list elements were already arrays doesn't make a difference.

The create and assign solution:

```
In [481]: a = np.empty(2, object)
In [482]: a
Out[482]: array([None, None], dtype=object)
In [483]: a[:]=[np.array([0, 1], dtype=int), np.array([1, 2], dtype=int)]
In [484]: a
Out[484]: array([array([0, 1]), array([1, 2])], dtype=object)
```

You could also add an extra element, eg. a `None` at the start, and slice it out after.

In any case, the trick is to get around `np.array` preference for making a multidimensional array where possible.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I think you would be better off going with a dictionary in this case.  Dictionaries are super fast to look up your arrays O(1) type of speed because they are a hash map.

```
import random

import numpy as np

my_sets = {}
for i in range(0, 10):
    my_sets[i] = (np.random.random(random.randint(1, 10)))

print(my_sets)
```

That code should give you numpy arrays of different sizes but make it really easy to look them up in a dictionary - this is at least how I do it at work

Comment: It is interesting solution, but I want to use "advanced indexing" capability of NumPy.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([np.array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int), np.array([3, 4], dtype=int)], dtype=object)
print(a[0].dtype, a[1].dtype)
```

Comment: How to use this trick for the following situation: a = np.array([np.random.randint(0,5,random.randint(1, 5)) for i in range(1)], dtype = object)

Comment: How to use this logic for creating arrays in dynamical way?

Comment: How's this different from the OP's first example?